# Have Excel QueryTable row numbers start at 1

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to adjust the starting number of a QueryTables row number? I have set QueryTable.RowNumbers = True but this starts counting at 0. I would like to start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `RowNumbers` to `True` doesn’t immediately cause row numbers to appear. The row numbers appear the next time the query table is refreshed, and they’re reconfigured every time the query table is refreshed.

`TextFileStartRow` property returns or sets the row number at which text parsing will begin when you import a text file into a query table.

(source: Microsoft's MSDN)